# Reliably deleting a temp file with python

Tags: python, windows

I have a application running on Windows 10 that uses Python 2.7 to write temporary files to disk and then open them with the associated application.

I have encountered unexpected behavior when cleaning up temporary .pdf files that have been opened with Edge.

If I have the following circumstances:

1. I have a .pdf file on disk
2. I open the .pdf with Edge
3. I call  [os.remove()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) on this file before closing the .pdf with Edge

Then this unexpected behavior occurs:

1. The first call to [os.remove()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) completes without exception,
2. A call to [os.path.isfile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) with this file's path return False.
3. However the file appears to remain on disk as it is displayed by File Explorer,
4. Subsequent calls to [os.remove()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) fail: "Access is denied",
5. And calls to [os.rmdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rmdir) for the parent directory fail: "The directory is not empty".

Finally when the .pdf file is closed by Edge:

1. The file is removed from the file system.

---

Is this "delayed-deletion" behaviour provided by the OS?

Is Edge keeping a non-exclusive lock on the file?

What is going on here?

Comment: This is normal Windows behavior for a file opened with delete sharing (i.e. `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`). The file can be 'deleted' but not unlinked until all references to it have been closed, and once 'deleted' no new handles can be created for any kind of access. Windows calls this setting the 'delete disposition' on the underlying file control block, and it can actually be toggled on and off repeatedly by any handle with delete access.

Comment: From the MSDN:  "*The DeleteFile function marks a file for deletion on close. Therefore, the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed.*".  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: TIL, I wonder why Edge opens pdfs with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`?

Comment: you could try using Window's `taskkill` called via Python's `subprocess` to kill the Edge process... then delete normally.

Comment: @KellyThomas, if it didn't share delete access, then `os.remove` would fail, so it solves some problems and changes the nature of other problems that would be a problem either way. Note that if the file can be opened for delete/rename access, it can also be moved out of the way to another directory on the same volume (but not to a different volume), such as maybe the user's temp directory or a new temp directory in the root of the volume.